# Cómo guardar objetos completos en Mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, json

Tengo una aplicacion Node.js, y al subirlo a un servidor compartido tuve un problema con `express-session`, ya que el mensaje de error decía que debía guardar las sesiones en un base de datos porque la aplicacion no podría tener más de una session a la vez, entonces usé `store` para guardar las sessions en mysql, hasta ahí todo bien, pero me surgió la duda de cuánto puedo almacenar en Node.js, porque tengo 3 variables que almacenan en un array 3 objetos grandes, uno almacena las subscripciones push de `web-push`, otro los sockets de `socket.io`, y otro los client de `whatsapp-web.js`, algo así:

```
var sockets_arr = [{cod:1, socket: socket}];
var whatsapp_arr = [{cod:1, client: socket}];
var push_subs_arr = [{cod:1, subs: socket}];
```

Así que las subscripciones push de Web-push también las guardé en mysql, y funcionó bien, pero al momento de guardar un `client` de whatsapp-web.js surge el problema, al hacer `JSON.stringify(client)` sale el error de que estoy convirtiendo un objeto circular, entonces lo intenté con `flutted`, y pude convertirlo en json y así mandar a mysql, pero al solicitarlo de mysql y parsearlo con `parse` de `flutted`, las funciones no son reconocidas, como `clent.destroy()` o cualquier otra función. Bueno en la documentación de `flutted` dice que no sirve para objetos tipo sockets o parecidos, así que supongo que es por eso.
Entonces mi pregunta es, cómo puedo guardar un client o socket en mysql? o si no se puede, cuánto puedo almacenar dentro de mi app.js en Node.js?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo del *objeto* que deseas guardar y el esquema de la tabla MySQL que usas para guardarlo? Suena a que no tienes realmente una estructura definida para el almacenamiento de los datos. Saludos

Comment: La tabla es igual que el array,, tiene una columna id tipo int, y una columna client tipo json, el objeto de client de whatsapp-web.js es bastante extenso y contiene funciones y recursividad, un solo client tiene más de 12000 bytes de información cuando lo convierto a json con la función stringify de flutted, pero como mencioné flutted no sirve para serializar objetos como sockets o parecidos, y client es más complejo aún que socket

Comment: Se crea el client con const client = new Client(); Esa constante es la que quiero guardar en mysql, convirtiéndolo a json me imagino que es la única forma, pero ni con flutted se puede conservar integro el objeto client. Esta es la documentación: https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatsapp-web.js/v/1.16.4-alpha.0

Comment: En el caso de que no haya forma de almacenarlo en mysql, me gustaría saber cuánto puedo hacer crecer una variable dentro del archivo que se ejecuta, en mi caso es app.js, cuánto puede crecer mi array? si cada cliente es {cod: x, client: client} y ese client es mínimo 12000 bytes, cuántos de esos clientes puedo almacenar en mi app.js? el procesador es de 4gb